# How to detect getty respawn?

Tags: linux, init, busybox

I am using BusyBox, however I think my question is generic. This is an example of what one of the tty lines looks like in my inittab file.

```
tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty -n -l /usr/bin/loginwrapper 38400 tty1
```

I want to know if there is a way to detect that the getty process has respawned.

So for example in my profile script I want to be able to run a command only the very first time getty spawns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a wrapper script which you can place there into your inittab, replacing the actual `getty` command.

In that script you can do your jobs and at the end you can start the `getty`.

So instead of the original inittab line you'll get something like this:

```
tty1::respawn:/usr/local/sbin/myscript 38400 tty1
```

And in that script:

```
#!bin/sh

LAST_BOOT=`who -b`
LAST_BOOT_FILE="/tmp/place/to/put/your/flags/$2"
if grep -q "$LAST_BOOT" $LAST_BOOT_FILE 2> /dev/null; then
    echo "Respawn"
else
    echo "$LAST_BOOT" > $LAST_BOOT_FILE
    echo "First start"
fi

exec /sbin/getty -n -l /usr/bin/loginwrapper $*
```

#### Update

If you have ramdisk, you can create a file on that and check its existence as a flag.

Comment: If the inittab respanws on your tty your script will be executed again.

Comment: You can place a flag file somewhere in your filesystem, with the last system boot time (`who -b`) and with the name of the actual tty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14560/discussion-between-plazgoth-and-karaszi-istvan)

Comment: I am using ramdisk, so this seems like the simplest approach. Thanks!